# Resetting iOS 7 microphone access permission

Tags: ios, ios7

How do I reset the microphone access permission so that the app will ask for microphone access permission again as if it were downloaded fresh from the App Store?

Reinstalling the app does not accomplish what I need. When I set the permissions in Settings->Privacy->Microphone, I can only turn permissions on or off. I need to reset it so that it asks for permissions again.

Comment: Have you tried removing the app first?

Comment: @Till Removing the app and building/installing it again just keeps the previous setting for mic permissions. It doesn't ask me again if I want to allow the mic, which is what I want.

Comment: @ill_always_be_a_warriors did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least starting from iOs 7.1.1 there are switches to change access permission for every single app.

Look in: Settings->Privacy, select the kind of subsytem of your interest ( eg: microphone ), you will see your app in the list. Change the value of the selector according to your needs.

Have a nice day, Stefano

Answer (score 50):

You can **RESET** your privacy settings in iOS Settings.

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy.

NOTE: **Privacy settings for all apps will be reset.**

Comment: Meaning, all your app's privacy options will be reset. There is no way to specify these settings for a unique app.

Comment: Agreed, this should be the correct answer. This is something you probably want to do an a dev iOS device (not your daily driver) in order to test functionality in your app.

Comment: this worked for me. frustrating that once you delete and reinstall an app nevertheless it remembers the last setting for the microphone. i am trying to test various scenarios around this

Comment: This still did not work for me w/r/t microphone. Had to give up on the simulator and test on device.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your bundle identifier, that'll also reset the permissions for your app.

Comment: Apparently no one tests permissions anymore. EASILY better than reseting the privacy settings for my entire device (I test on my personal device). Just make sure you change the identifier back before archiving the build!

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for an uninstalled app are reset after a day.

So, if it is not urgent, you can wait for it reset. I know this is not an ideal solution but it is app specific

Comment: "Permissions for an uninstalled app are reset after a day." Source?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Stefano's post - if you'd like to direct your user directly to the microphone settings then you can use:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
app.openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=Privacy&path=MICROPHONE")!)
```

(at least on iOS 9 - if the Settings app structure changes, then the link will likely need to change)